# Way to build an app in which user fills a form that can be downloaded or emailed as a PDF?

Tags: javascript, cordova, pdf, server, phonegap

I'm working on an app through Phonegap (written in HTML/CSS/JS) that's intended to have the user fill out a form (radio buttons, text boxes, etc.) which will then be either downloadable (as PDF) or simply sent to a specific email upon completion (as a PDF).

I've been using a JavaScript function that prints the page as a PDF that's automatically downloaded at the click of a button on the bottom of the page.

But I've noticed that the Print to PDF function doesn't seem to be a true PDF in the sense that I can't highlight the printed text within the resultant PDF. Additionally, the amount of information in each print seems to have a limit. I can't get it to print content on the page beyond a certain length. I also am not sure that this works on mobile, but it seems to work when tested in the browser on Chrome (with some issues).

What's the best way to create a PDF after the user fills out the form? I've read that I can maybe create something server-side and have the app send a PDF (via email) from a server after the user fills out the information on the page. Does this sound right?

Can I make it so that the user fills out the information in the app, clicks a button, and then the information on the app is saved and a PDF of said information is sent via email? I'm not quite sure how to set up a server to do this if even possible.

Simply, I just want my clients to fill out the info in the app, and then click a button on the bottom of the page that then takes that information and spits out a PDF. I'm having trouble finding an effective way to actually do this.

Here's my code thus far (sans head, CSS):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-c9vxcXyAG4paArQG3xk6DjyW/9aHxai2ef9RpMWO44A=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>

    <div id="content2" class="app">      
        <h1><u>4-Point Inspection</u></h1>

        <br>

        <div class="border">
        <center><form>
          <label for="fname">Insured/Applicant Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        </form></center>
        <center><form>
          <label for="fname">Application/Policy #</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        </form></center>
        <center><form>
          <label for="fname">Address Inspected</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        </form></center>
        <center><form>
          <label for="fname">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        </form></center>
        <center><form>
          <label for="fname">Actual Year Built</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        </form></center>
        <center><form>
          <label for="fname">Email</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        </form></center>
        <center><form>
          <label for="fname">Date Inspected</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        </form></center></div>

    </div>

    <center><button class="btn btn-info" id="downloadPDF">Download PDF</button></center>

    <script>$('#downloadPDF').click(function () {
        domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('content2'))
            .then(function (blob) {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#content2').width(), $('#content2').height()]);

                pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#content2').width(), $('#content2').height());
                pdf.save("test.pdf");

                that.options.api.optionsChanged();
            });
    }); </script>
```

Here's the Javascript function (also shown at the end of the above code):

```
$('#downloadPDF').click(function () {
            domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('content2'))
                .then(function (blob) {
                    var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#content2').width(), $('#content2').height()]);
    
                    pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#content2').width(), $('#content2').height());
                    pdf.save("test.pdf");
    
                    that.options.api.optionsChanged();
                });
        });
```

I simply want a way to turn this interactive form into a PDF that's either downloadable or just emailed to a specific email address - I just don't know the most effective way to do this.

Any and all help/recommendations would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator

> Simple plugin to generate (offline) pdf. the plugin transform HTML to
> PDF and also provide the mechanism to share the pdf to other apps like
> Mail, etc. For now works in iOS and Android, if you want to add other
> platform feel free contribute.
>
> The iOS HTML to PDF transformation is based in this work BNHtmlPdfKit,
> I just add a new method to allow transformation between plain HTML to
> PDF.